# How to substitute a function into another function in maxima

Tags: maxima

I am a quite beginner in Maxima.
I am wondering if I can do the following:

I want to get a partial differential of a function like:

```
depends(w_r,[r]);
depends(w_theta,[theta]);
depends(e_r,[r]);
depends(e_theta,[theta]);
f(r,theta):=diff(w_r*e_r+w_theta*e_theta,r,1);
```

f(r,theta) includes the term de_r /dr, but I know de_r/dr = 0.
Is there a way to tell to Maxima that de_r/dr = 0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but subst(diff(e_r,r,1)=0) looks working.